# How to save username in global variable asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have online exam system I want to save username in global variable or any other thing that just can save it.
I want this username for get and set data on SQL database. 
I'm using a global variable in class but it replace in every login.
any way to save username foreach user?

```
 public class GVar
{
    public static string user
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public static string mail
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public static string melli
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public static bool go
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static System.Threading.Thread thread { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of `Session`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Application` or `Session` as the case may be.
Session variables are global but limited to current session (call it user for understanding).
Application variables are globally shared across all sessions.
So, following statements may be used to get/set variables at application level

```
Application["user"] = "abc";     //sets the value at application level
var user = Application["user"];  //gets the value stored at application level
```

Similarly, to make it global, but isolate at session level,

```
Session["user"] = "abc";     //sets the value at session level
var user = Session["user"];  //gets the value stored at session level
```

**EDIT**

For ease of use, I prefer implementing them as properties, somewhat like this:

1. Define the class with custom getter/setter properties, and add it to `App_Code` folder

   ```
   public static class GVar
   {
       public static string user
       {
           get { return Session["GVar_User"]; }
           set { Session["GVar_User"] = value; }
       }

       //...

   }
   ```
2. Use it in your application, as you would normally do with any other property.

   ```
       GVar.user = "abc";      //set value
       var usr = GVar.user;    //get value
   ```

Comment: You definitely don't want to store username at the application level - that limits the whole site to only one user at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You can save it on login like this:

```
Session["user"] = "gamesdl";
```

And then you can get the value during executing like this:

```
String username = (string)(Session["user"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use claims.
The claims are in identity. And you can config then in login action.

Comment: I am using webform ;|

Comment: Your goal is not very clear for me! but i think You can use cookies, sessions, static variables or etc